# Load testing selenium scripts in visual studio

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load-testing, visualstudio

I am wondering if someone has some advice for running load testing in visual studio, preferably with a selenium webdriver script. I know that JUnit can be integrated with JMeter, so that you can test load on a certain automated test. But I cannot find any information on load testing in visual studio with a selenium type script. Basically, the test is login to the system as a user, get requirements for student, upload documents, and submit the file. This is easily achieved in selenium, but I am wondering how to simulate 1, 10, 25, 100, MAX users. Thanks for your insight ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend looking into Visual Studio load test tool. You will need an Ultimate license. This tool will make it much easier to do all the things necessary to create a *useful* performance test while minimizing time to script and hardware needed to drive the test.

You can read more here...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd293540(v=vs.110).aspx

I understand you have the Selenium scripts already created but that will not save you much time compared to what it would take to scale out a Selenium test into a valid/useful performance test. Using Selenium to performance test would adding a layer between Visual Studio and the system under test that is not needed. It would be the wrong tool for the job. I hope this helps!

Comment: Do I have to have an ultimate license to do load testing? Currently I have professional 2013.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do, but old versions of NUnit doesn’t deal well with multi-threaded code.  Ie NUnit itself was design to be single threaded.
You can use [PNunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5) which will give you that functionality.

Using NUnit 3 or above has PNunit included.  You can find more information on how to use it on [this page](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parallelizable&r=3.0)